# What are the usage of resteasy jar packages in webapp war and jboss module?

Tags: java, jboss

I have thought resteasy is provided by the jboss container, therefore at the first time I did not put it into the maven pom dependency.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

However it failed. It worked after I remove the scope tag from the pom file. And I have check the jar of resteasy-jaxrs in the war package is the same the that in the jboss module directory.

```
 Directory of D:\GreenProgram\jboss-as-7.0.2.Final\modules\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\main

2017/04/12  13:35    <DIR>          .
2017/04/12  13:35    <DIR>          ..
2011/09/22  22:35             1,856 module.xml
2011/09/22  22:35             5,865 resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA-jandex.jar
2017/04/12  13:35                10 resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA-jandex.jar.index
2011/09/22  22:35           576,962 resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar
2017/04/12  13:35             1,379 resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar.index
               5 File(s)        586,072 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  126,404,255,744 bytes free
```

Any expert can help me understand the jboss module mechanism?

Comment: What does "it failed" means? Can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: You can refer the link: (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) whuich descibes the classloading in JBoss and Jboss module.

Comment: @Francesco Thanks your attention. It is strange that I cannot reproduce the problem on the resteasy jar. I set the scope to "provided" back and it still work correctly. However I found the same problem on another jar: javassist. I set its scope to "provided" and got the exception.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter from [Module "deployment.ossrcrest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
        at 
        ... 49 more` However, this jar can be found in $JBOSS_HOME/modules\org\javassist\main\javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar

Comment: In JBoss 7/WIldfly not all the modules are loaded by default. Someone are loaded when certain conditions are met (put a beans.xml or a JAX-RS annotation) or by explicit dependency declared in MANIFEST.MF or in jboss-deployment-structure.xml (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments) ).